# Работа с данными с помощью таблиц html

Tags: javascript, html, mvc

Здравствуйте
У меня есть таблица, по аналогии с учебным журналом (строки - студенты, столбцы - даты, на пересечении отметка). Мне нужно как-то реализовать возможность изменения данных в ячейках, что бы я мог при этом получить и дату, и студента, и затем отправить запрос с этими данными. Или же каким-то образом хранить id отметки и при изменении в таблице просто посылать новое значение.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно лучше реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Начнём с того что изменение и сохранение данных это дело которое слабо касается html.
Для отправки данных можно в таблице сделать какое-то количество инпутов. ОТправлять можно как всей формой, так и ajax-cом с помощью js.
Далее нужно выбрать платформу для обработки этих данных.
Сами данные можно сохранить как файле так и в какой-то бд.

---

Я вижу реализацию так:

БД из 3-х таблиц

СТУДЕНТЫ
id|fio

Предмет
id|subject

Оценки
id|student_id|subject|appraisal

При изменении в какой-то ячейке данных отправлять ajax запрос на сервер и сохранять отметку.

Comment: все верно, схема бд примерно такая как вы и указали
отправлять я собираюсь ajax-ом.
Вопрос состоит в том, какие данные отправлять на сервер и как их выбрать из таблицы, если например на сервер отправляется только новое значение и id, то где тогда хранить id? Само значение ведь мы вводим, а вот id..;